# Where can I buy good looking, unenchanted apparel?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'd like to buy good looking unenchanted apparel and then enchant it myself.

Where are the main vendors for cloth apparel, necklaces, and rings?

Comment: Good looking is fairly subjective.

Answer (score 11):

[Radiant Raiment](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Radiant_Raiment) in Solitude sells many many different styles of clothing, ranging from ragged clothes all the way up to the more expensive fine clothes.

They also sell jewelry, although your best bet for making the best jewelry (except for circlets) is crafting them yourself via smithing.

Comment: Beware though - they are not known for their stellar customer service.

Answer (score 1):

When completing the dark brotherhood quest line you can get hold of emperor clothing. Worth 100. Looks good. Also wedding clothing can be taken from the bride following the same quest line.

Answer (score 0):

These mods allow you to disenchant many of the enchanted items in the game, allowing you to put your own enchantment on them:

**[EzEs -Artifact Disenchanting](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/8157)**

> Changed some of the artifacts and unique weapons in Skyrim so that you can now disenchant them, and learn their effects, allowing you to place artifact enchantments on normal weapons. All armor/clothing enchantments can go on any item of clothing/armor.

**[Master Enchant Disenchant and more powerful Enchanting](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/4735)**

> Adds the ability to disenchant several Unique items and Artifacts and adds the effects to your enchant menu so you can use them just like any other enchantments. 16 OF THEM! In addition, all of the Armor enchantments in this package can be used on ANY piece of armor or jewelry- no restrictions to type. I would also recommend the "I put a spell on you" mod at skyrim nexus so you use all the other default armor enchantments on any piece of armor with no restrictions as well.In addition, with this mod you can dramitically increase the power/ number of charges with the optional mod files included in the zip.

**[Disenchantment Font - Wipe old enchantments from items](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/31967)**

> This mod allows you to remove enchantments from weapons and armour, reverting them to their base item state via the use of a 'Disenchantment Font'.
>
> To remove an enchantment from an item, search the Disenchantment Font then 'store' any item you want disenchanted into the Disenchantment Font. The font will then spend a few seconds removing the enchantment then it will put the disenchanted item back into your inventory. If a disenchantment couldn't be performed then the item will be placed back into your inventory the same as you put it in.

[More 'disenchant' mods can be found by searching Skyrim Nexus.](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/searchresults/?name=disenchant&orderby=OLD_endorsements&sort=DESC)

Comment: You know that this does not answer the question at all, don't you ?

Comment: @Nigralbus From http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/6965/4797: "*It's OK to answer a question and provide additional information to the asker that they didn't specifically ask for. Actually, I'd consider this to be good form and highly encouraged.*" "*Often times a sub-par question elicits a short, to-the-point answer which answers the question as asked, but doesn't provide a solution to the problem the asker is facing. It's possible to ask a better question, but it's also possible to look past the specific thing being asked - the non-expert question - and find the underlying problem.*"

Comment: @Nigralbus OP was looking for unenchanted apparel so that he could enchant it himself. My answer gave info on how to do that.